# Getting and installing dartium

Tags: software-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu and am a little confused on how to get and run dartium.
I went to the [dartium homepage](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dartium/) and downloaded the zip package for linux distros, but I don't really understand what is inside (I'm on a 64-bit build of Ubuntu):

[image]

Basically, I do not see an executable named `Chromium` anywhere as I was expecting and see no README or anything to tell me how what any of these files do. My main question is after I download the zip file and extract it, what do I do from here to be able to run dartium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The executable is named `chrome`. I'm not sure why they posted that the executable is named `Chromium`, since it hasn't been named that for a long time.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful and led me to the answer (see my answer).

Comment: @JesseGood Based on your question, that should be the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

As the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/663527/367165) correctly points out, the executable is named `chrome` and not `chromium` on linux. On top of that, I found the problem [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/12325).

I used the temporary workaround which is to create a link:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

The issue was posted two years ago, it's unfortunate a fix has not been made yet...